# Show some error message saying wrong parameter pointing to particular input filed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to show some message (with or without focus) pointing to particular input field if that field was found incorrect after validation saying for example "Entered value is wrong".

I know it is very naive question, but was not able to find answer for it.

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you working with?

Comment: Please put some code snippet showing what have you already tried, so we can help. Never create such a generic question.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Questions like this are too broad. See [ask]

Comment: Sorry for it as i am new and  will not be posting generic question like this.In my code i applied simple validation using javascript and i thought i should simply ask how to do this without posting my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags contains jQuery so here's a method:

**Step 1:** Download and include jQuery to your project or include it from cdn 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

**Step 2:** Include the jQuery Validation Plugin
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js

**Step 3:** HTML form. (Example)

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Registration</h2>
  <form action="" name="registration">

    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="John"/>

    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Doe"/>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="john@doe.com"/>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="****"/>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

**Step 4:** Some styling to make it cool (Like stackoverflow, facebook etc, as you mentioned above :p)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

form {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #2c3e50;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
form label,
form input,
form button {
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
form input {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 6px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form button {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #e67e22;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Step 5:** The jQuery script for validation

```
$(function() {
  $("form[name='registration']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
      lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
      password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
      },
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

**Update**: Replying to the comment.

**Expected Output**:
[image]

**Note:** If you need more styling of the error messages, edit the CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh ,  I have tried your code but it is only pointing to email field if it  is incorrect. How to do for others fields?

Comment: The code should work for all the fields (firstname, lastname, email and password) specified in the form. Check if you have any errors in your developer console.

Comment: I have checked it going to console,it says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file.html?firstname=&lastname=&email=kkgkg%40gm.og&password=:15)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.B (jquery.min.js:2)" . i have simply copied your code and added libraries you provided.So how to reslove it?

Comment: First you need to include `jquery.min.js` then `jquery.validate.min.js` and then the jQuery code mentioned above. Check if it's in the proper order in your project.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't include jquery.validate.min.js properly now working but only focusing and showing error message below incorrect field but i want as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: Work with your code, if you face any problem you can post your code in a different question and the community will help you with that. Kindly mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the "Tick Mark". Happy coding :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer @Saurabh. Is your code giving error message at position mentioned in question on your machine?

Comment: But i want that error message should appear right side of the input field as a  box with some edge pointing to that field.Hope you understand what i am trying to say.